# Table of Contents Placement Setting

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using {report} class, wanted to include Table of Contents in the Table of Contents, but it became...strange...

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
    \section{ABSTRACT}
    Some text text text
    \newpage

    \section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
    Some more text text text
    \newpage

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I searched to make ToC section, but it seems it is waayy above my league. I am new to LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), that shows the issue of your screenshot. When I add `\documentclass{report}` to your example, I get https://i.imgur.com/GR7Ky4Z.png and cannot see the issue. However note: The top level with `report` is `\chapter` not `\section`. So you should either replace all `section` in your example with `chapter` or use `article` instead of `report`. See a LaTeX introduction for more information about the classes.

Comment: ahh, I also changed numbering;

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

the source of the problem might be this ?

Comment: In this case, I would suggest to remove the change and just use `article` instead if `report`. It does not make sense, to use `report` and try to change it to behave like `article`.

Comment: Try `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}TABLE OF CONTENTS}`. (But this is a quite odd idea. Who would ever look up in the table of contents the location of the table of contents?)

Comment: I don't know @UlrikeFischer , I'm just following the thesis guide. They showed ToC in ToC lol
BTW your code is working, thank you!

Comment: @cabohah I wanted to use \chapter but it creates Chapter 1-2-3.. etc..getting rid of these lines from pages as well as headers seems requiring more work than adjusting the \section...That was my reason to use \section s..
As for `article`, I searched google and most people used `report` for thesis..That was my beginning point..

Comment: There are packages to configure the headings. Or just use `scrreprt` instead of `report`. The default there is without the “Chapter N” line. Or use `article` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using class `report`, but eliminate usage of `\chapter` does not make much sense. It also does not work, because the table of contents and the list of figures etc. will still be chapters (using `\chapter*`). So, either use `\chapter`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ABSTRACT}
    Some text text text

    \chapter{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
    Some more text text text

    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image: using report]

or use `article` instead of `report`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\contentsname}}
\begin{document}
    \section{ABSTRACT}
    Some text text text

    \section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
    Some more text text text

    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image: with article]

However, adding an entry for the table of contents into the table of contents does not make much sense. If you are already inside the table of contents you don't benefit from the information. If you are not already in the table of contents, you don't get the information.

Comment: Our dissertation guide included ToC in the ToC..That wasn't my idea..I'm just following their example..